# Equivalent of Java's String.getBytes("UTF-8") in c++?

Tags: java, c++, string

I need to implement this Java code in (unmanaged) c++:

```
byte[] b = string.getBytes("UTF8");
```

I'm new to c++, and can't find anything to do this. It has to be platform independent, if possible. Using c++11 compiler.

Comment: Use [`std::basic_string::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

Comment: Depending on the encoding of the input string, you should consider to convert the encoding the string before getting the bytes from it. Use for example the [character set conversions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html) from Boost.Locale.

Comment: The input string currently it's only a string literal in code, does that have an encoding? if yes, how do I know which is being used?

Comment: It depends on what encoding you use for your C++ strings. You are [free to assume they are UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) and then anything written by people below will work. Anyway it depends on some context beyond this single line of code: Where you got the string from? How you use the `bytes` afterwards? etc...

Comment: If you use ASCII characters in the literal, it is compatible to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java `String` is roughly equivalent to `std::u16string`, a specialization of [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). I suggest you try something like...

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
std::string converted = convert.to_bytes(u"HELLO, WORLD!");
const char *bytes = converted.data();
```

**Note** this relies on C++11; it might be sometime before your compiler vendor fully supports these features.

Here, we utilize the newly introduced [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) to convert from a wide-character UTF-16 string to the UTF-8 multibyte string via [`to_bytes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes) (it also supports conversion in the other direction, too).

This is made possible via the (also newly introduced) [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) conversion facet. It takes care of the actual conversion for us nicely.

Besides that, it makes use of the new character literal prefixes added with C++11 -- in particular, `u`, which is for `char16_t` UTF-16 strings :-) There are also `u8` and `U` for UTF-8 and UTF-32, respectively.

---

PS `data` is (as of C++11) guaranteed to be equal to `c_str` and therefore can be relied upon to be NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution Number 1:-

```
 char bytecpp[]= u8"You don't need strings.getbytes :P";
```

Solution Number 2:-

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>> myconv;
std::string mbstring = myconv.to_bytes(u"Hello\n");
std::cout << mbstring;
```

Comment: That was fairly shameless... by the way, `wchar_t` need not be correct here. Read my answer for the alternative `u` prefix and `char16_t`.

Comment: @veer:- Sorry to get you, I waited for some one to answer about that `u8`. May be solution two seems a copy of you but I coincidentally  copied it from $22.3.3.2.2 of N3337 Pg.654. :)

Comment: I wasn't being serious... I just want the OP to have his question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is already in UTF-8, you can use:

```
char const *c = myString.c_str();
```

For read/write access, you could use:

```
std::vector<char> bytes(myString.begin(), myString.end());
bytes.push_back('\0');
char *c = &bytes[0];
```

Comment: +1, but note that &myString[0] will work for read/write access just as well (strings are contiguous since C++11), although won't be null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

A string in C++ is typically ASCII 1 byte per character.  So you would have to take care of it before you marshaled it to C++ if you went with the typical std::string.  However C++ does define a wide character string std::wstring, unfortunately(from the wikipedia article on wide characters):

> The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text. The wchar_t type is intended for storing compiler-defined wide characters, which may be Unicode characters in some compilers.

So we would have to know what C++ compiler you were going to use to answer the question completely.  For the std::wstring class there is no to bytes type function, so what you want to do is use c_str() as mentioned in the other answers then use &(bit wise and) and a byte mask to split the wide characters in to bytes.

in visual C++ a wide character is 16 bits so you would want something like the following to process each characters in to bytes:

```
high_byte = wcharacter & 0xFF00;
low_byte = wcharacter & 0xFF;
```

Comment: "...unfortunately: The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific..." Which implies that we can assume by convention that [C++ strings are UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) unless said otherwise. EDIT: and your code definitely does not convert to UTF-8.

Comment: If you mention wchar_t, the [utf-8 everywhere manifesto](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) comes in to my mind. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @ybungalobill in the present, you can't, because that convention is not assumed everywhere (and that's exactly why that document exists).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: In the real world this is what I do, company I work do, and many libraries do (e.g. Boost.Locale, pugixml, gtkmm, etc...).